# AWS Serverless Image Handler - Version 5 - Lambda running on Node.js 12 End of Life

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I've recently taken over a project that has AWS Serverless Image Handler version 5 implemented. And I've been sent various emails from the client they received about Node.js v12 hitting end of life and the Lambda functions needing to run on a new Node.js runtime.

Having a looking through the AWS account, I've seen I can just switch the runtime to Node.js v14 or v16, but do I need to do any code updates?

Sorry a complete noob to Lambda, and the CloudFormation stacks etc

Thought I would ask before I jump down the rabbit hole and look at setting up my own copy of Serverless Image Handler and doing some testing, or even trying to implement version 6.

Answer (score 1):

This depends of the code / imported libraries in the Serverless Image Handler Lambda.

I would check if there are breaking changes in Node14, that could affect the code.

This does not have anything to do with Lambda / CF itself.